# With autoHotKey code, how can I write a function that receives the autohotkey command text as a parameter and executes it?

Tags: function, parameters, command, autohotkey

for example I want to pass ANY ahk command text like "Click, 50, 50" or "MsgBox test",,, into a function and execute that command. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you.

```
#SingleInstance, Force

    var := "example"
    new_instance(   "msgbox " var " 1`nexitapp" )
    new_instance(   "msgbox % ""another " var " 2"""
                .   "`nexitapp" )
    new_instance(   "msgbox another example 3`nexitapp" )
    new_instance(   "msgbox passing var`n"
                .   "var := """ var " 4""`n"
                .   "Msgbox % var `n"
                .   "exitapp" )

ExitApp, 0

new_instance( Script )  {

    OutputDebug, % script   ;   for debug purpose
    shell   := ComObjCreate( "WScript.Shell" )
    exec    := shell.Exec( A_AhkPath " /ErrorStdOut *")
    exec.StdIn.Write( script )
    exec.StdIn.Close()

}
```

Comment: It goes well. I thought this was an impossible feature. I appreciate it.

Comment: But shouldn't it be the case of "MouseMove, 10, 10, Relative"? I'm getting an error. Isn't that code applicable to all other AHK commands?

Comment: new_instance(   "MouseMove, 10, 10, Relative`nexitapp" )


It's working quite well for me on 1.1.36.02 V1.It's applicable to any code, but it's important to note that each code sent to this function is treated as a new instance. Therefore, it's advisable to review the output code carefully.


Can you post your function call?

Comment: I must have done something wrong. Now that's great. I appreciate it

Comment: Can this script be run in an environment where autohotkey is not installed?That's because there seems to be an error in the A_AhkPath part in an environment where autohotkey is not installed. Is all I need is the autohotkey.exe file?

Comment: Probably not (I'm not 100% certain), as it opens a new instance of the script. Theoretically, if launched from an executable in an environment without AutoHotkey installed, it would generate an error, but I've never tested it.